# Would a HashMap require more memory than a linked list?

Tags: memory, linked-list, hashmap

From what I understand of hashmaps, the inner data structure can be seen as a 2D array. The first index would be the "key" and the second index would be the array containing the values that hash to the same key. In my mind, you would need to initialize a sufficiently large array to account for future entries(or else you would need to enlarge the array at some point or all values hash to the same value). Because of the initial cost of initializing an array of a certain size, this would mean hashmaps have a high initial cost vs a linkedlist.

Linkedlist only need as much memory as required to represent X number of items. Am I correct in this assumption? I'm only confused because many people say LinkedList use more memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just some numbers:

An empty HashMap requires 128 bytes:
The overhead is 64 bytes plus 36 bytes per entry.
For 10K entries, the expected overhead is ~360K

An empty LinkedList requires 48 bytes:
The overhead is 24 bytes, plus 24 bytes per entry.
For 10K entries, the expected overhead is ~240K

source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/

[image: Image from google search]

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that Maps have keys and values.   So for every item in the list, there are 2 in the Map.  So if a LinkedList will cost `n` in terms of storage, the Map will require `2n`.   In addition to that, as you pointed out, you have to have some free space, so now you are up to 2n + 2n*.c, which is (1+c)2n, where c is some fraction like .25.

So does this qualify as 'high' space requirements compared to a linked list?  I don't think so, unless you have constrained memory requirements.  Remember, you also gain constant time access to any elements, where for a linked list its O(n) for access.

Finally, because Maps work with problems that have keys and values, and lists are primarily concerned with just values, the problems to which you apply these datastructures tend to be different, so the question might not make much sense.